# Anyone know how to record and playback a recording with Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to implement a simple 'voicemail' sort of system, where the voicemail owner can record their own greeting.

I figured I could do something like this:

```
  response.Say("Record your message");
  response.Record(recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("http://<snip>.ngrok.io/voice/playmessage"));
  response.Say("Are you happy with this recording?");
  return TwiML(response);
```

then in the playmessage method

```
  [HttpPost]
  public TwiMLResult PlayMessage()
  {
    string url = Request.Form["RecordingUrl"];
    var vr = new VoiceResponse();
    vr.Play(url: new Uri(url));
    return TwiML(vr);
  }
```

It's hanging up right after the record, then the PlayMessage method gets called.

I tried adding a RecordingEventEnum.InProgress, like this:

```
response.Record(recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("http://<snip>.ngrok.io/voice/playmessage"), recordingStatusCallbackEvent: new List<Record.RecordingEventEnum> {Record.RecordingEventEnum.InProgress });
```

and the method APPEARS to be called, but it doesn't play anything and just hangs up.

I haven't gotten to the all the 'Press 1 if you're happy with your recording, press 2 to try again, etc...' stuff.

I figure I'm not calling the 'record' method correctly...does anyone know the magic sauce?

thanks,

Gene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `action` attribute instead of the `recordingStatusCallback`:

```
response.Record(action: new Uri("http://<snip>.ngrok.io/voice/playmessage"));
```

From the [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record):

> The `action` attribute takes a relative or absolute URL as a value. When recording is finished, Twilio will make a GET or POST request to this URL including the parameters below.

(Note "parameters below" include the `RecordingUrl`.)

Be careful though:

> There is one exception: if Twilio receives an empty recording, it will not make a request to the `action` URL. The current call flow will continue with the next verb in the current TwiML document.

That being said your `response.Say("Are you happy with this recording?");` should be part of the `PlayMessage()` after the `Play`.

Also have a look at the example [Record a voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record?code-sample=code-record-a-voicemail&code-language=Ruby&code-sdk-version=5.x) from the Twilio API doc.

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thank you.